# android json object string display in textview

Tags: android, arrays, json, string

I am trying to display data in textviews that are exracted from a json array.

i get a correct server answer and the first toast displays correctly de json array {"android":{"total":4}}

The php page is online http://www.2w.cl/apps/db/cargar_resultados.php

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SeeResults extends Activity{

    TextView texto;

    JSONArray android = null;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    private static String url = "http://www.2w.cl/apps/db/cargar_resultados.php/";
    private static final String TAG_OS = "android";
    private static final String TAG_CONSULTA = "total";

    public String idconsulta;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.see_results);
        idconsulta = getIntent().getStringExtra("test");

        TextView tv = null;
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText(idconsulta);

        Toast.makeText(this, "On Create Called" + idconsulta, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
        new JSONParse().execute();
        Toast.makeText(this, "On Start Called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

       @Override
         protected void onPreExecute() {
             super.onPreExecute();

       }
       @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("idconsultas", idconsulta));
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST", params);

            return json;
        }

        @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "test" + json, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          try {
             android = json.getJSONArray(TAG_OS);
             for(int i = 0; i < android.length(); i++){  
             JSONObject c = android.getJSONObject(i);

             String total = c.getString(TAG_CONSULTA);
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "test2" + total, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             TextView tv = null;
             tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
             tv.setText(total);
             }
         } catch (JSONException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
         }

        }
     }


}
```

the toast "test2" does not display anything.

Thanks for helping

Comment: post logcat (and read it, you'll see that it explains that your json response is not an array.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Response json string is:

> {"android":{"total":4}}

where `android` is `JSONObject` instead of `JSONArray` so get JSONObject from `json` JSONObject:

```
JSONObject  android = json.getJSONObject(TAG_OS);
String total = android.optString(TAG_CONSULTA);
```

Comment: i changed as stated but now i cant useJSONObject c = android.getJSONObject(i);

Comment: @IngolfKrauss: see my answer not need to use for loop and other code

Answer (score 0):

1. While debugging, use "Log.d" instead of Toasts
2. I would avoid putting Toasts inside a loop
3. It's untested, but give this code a shot:

   ```
   String result = "{\"android\":{\"total\":\"4\"}}";
   Log.d("something", "result: " + result);
   try {
       JSONObject hold = new JSONObject(result);
       JSONObject obj = hold.getJSONObject("android");
       Log.d("something", "total: " + obj.getString("total"));

   } catch (JSONException e) {
       Log.d("something", "ERROR");
   }
   ```

Comment: oh and your number 4 needs to be inside double quotes afaik